# Как предоставить локальному пользователю pdb права на v_$session, dba?

Tags: oracle

Подскажите, после установки 18 добавил бд `orclpdb` и локального пользователя `oratest` в `pdb`.
Есть 2-е проблемы:
При рестарте компьютера приходится каждый раз открывать бд `orclpdb`;
Пользователь `oratest` не видит `v$session` и `dba` таблицы(`dba_users, dba_roles` и тд):ORA-00942: таблица или представление пользователя не существует;

Если я правильно понял `tnsname` это CDB:

```
ORCL =
     (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

я добавил PDB:

```
ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

Все попытки дать гранты для `oratest` срабатывают но не дают видимости:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 
Connected as sys@ORCLPDB AS SYSDBA

    SQL> GRANT SELECT ON sys.v_$session TO ORATEST;
Grant succeeded

    SQL> select user from dual;
USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS

    SQL> select user from dual;
USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PUBLIC

    SQL> GRANT SELECT ON v_$session TO ORATEST;

Grant succeeded

    SQL> grant sysdba to ORATEST;

Grant succeeded

    SQL> grant connect, sysdba to ORATEST;
Grant succeeded

    SQL> grant dba to ORATEST;
Grant succeeded


    SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, SYSOPER, PDB_DBA, DBA, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO ORATEST;
Grant succeeded

    SQL> grant execute on dbms_lock to ORATEST;
Grant succeeded

    SQL> alter session set container = ORclpdb;
Session altered

    SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, SYSOPER, PDB_DBA, DBA, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO ORATEST;
Grant succeeded

    SQL> alter session set container = ORclpdb;
Session altered

    SQL> GRANT SELECT ON v_$session TO ORATEST;
Grant succeeded
```

Команды выше дали только доступ к `dbms_lock`

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых случаях может случиться, что у вас есть доступ к базе данных Oracle, но вы не можете настроить установку `Light Sampling Sessions`, поскольку у вас ограниченные права доступа, например, у вас нет системной привилегии `CREATE TABLE`. 
Однако с некоторыми ограниченными привилегиями вы можете отобразить график на средних активных сеансах.

**Создание пользователя**

Давайте создадим пользовательскую `PLSS` в контейнере `PDB1`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=PDB1;
CREATE USER PLSS IDENTIFIED BY plss CONTAINER=CURRENT;
```

Этот пользователь будет иметь только привилегию `CREATE SESSION` и будет иметь доступ к представлению `v$session`:

**Права пользователя**

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO PLSS;
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO PLSS;
```

**Создание табличного пространства PDB**

Мы создадим одно и то же табличное пространство во всех `PDB` (в нашем случае `PDB1`):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "LSS_REPOSITORY" DATAFILE
  'C:\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\ORCL\PDB1\LSS_REPOSITORY01.DBF' SIZE 5 M
  AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 2 G
  LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192
  EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
```

**Создание обычного пользователя**

Подключившись к контейнеру `CDB$ROOT`, мы создадим обычного пользователя `CLSS`:

```
CREATE USER CLSS IDENTIFIED BY lss
  CONTAINER=ALL
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE LSS_REPOSITORY
  QUOTA UNLIMITED ON LSS_REPOSITORY;
```

**Базовые привилегии**

Мы предоставим следующие привилегии пользователю `CLSS`:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO CLSS;
GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE TO CLSS;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO CLSS;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO CLSS;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO CLSS;
```

**Другие привилегии**

Давайте предоставим привилегию `SELECT` для базового объекта представления `v$session`, чтобы использовать его в процедуре:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO CLSS;
```

Давайте предоставим привилегию `EXECUTE` для пакета `DBMS_LOCK`:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOCK TO CLSS;
```

v$session - это представление, содержащее данные, связанные с несколькими контейнерами (`CDB$ROOT, PDB`). Поскольку обычный пользователь `CLSS` должен видеть данные всех этих контейнеров, мы установим атрибут `CONTAINER_DATA` следующим образом:

```
ALTER USER CLSS
 SET CONTAINER_DATA = (CDB$ROOT,PDB1)
 FOR v_$session CONTAINER=CURRENT;
```

Comment: Интересный эффект, я начал по вашей инструкции эксперимент с локальным новым пользователем и обнаружил что у моего пользователя появились все требуемые grantы которые я 3й день не мог накатить

Comment: `alter session set container=ORCLPDB;`  

`CREATE USER devtest IDENTIFIED BY xxxx CONTAINER=CURRENT;

GRANT CREATE SESSION TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$SESSION TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON v_$sqltext TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON v_$sqltext_with_newlines TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON v_$sess_io TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON v_$session_longops TO devtest;

GRANT SELECT ON v_$sesstat TO devtest;
GRANT SELECT ON v_$statname TO devtest;

grant connect, dba to devtest;` После этих команд мой предыдущий пользователь oratest вдруг заработал

Comment: Это глюк oracle или меня¿

Comment: Я использую plsql developer 11.0.6.1796 и в окнах открытых со вчера доступа нет, не смотря на переключение коннекта. Вновь открытый developer имеет доступ без проблем. Спасибо за участие и форматирование кода.

Comment: Oracle Documentation всегда в помощь или Google)

Comment: закройте вопрос.